# Selenium Java - Find Element & Click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am dealing with Selenium-Java.
For that I need to perform an automatization on a web page.
I am not able to "click" one of the buttons that prevents me from doing further steps.

The underlying HTML code is:

```
<div class="tm-element tm-pb" data-type="button" data-columns="1">
    <div class="tm-element-inner">
        <div class="tm-columns">
            <div class="tm-column">
                <div class="tm-button-container">
                    <a class="tm-button" data-align="center">
                        <div class="tm-button-label">
                            <p>Start now</p>
                        </div>
                        <span class="tm-button-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to click the Button saying **Start now**.

I extraced the xpath as well as the css information.
It seems that I am able to find the element via:
`findElement(By.cssSelector(".tm-visible > .tm-element .tm-columns .tm-button"));`

Moreover, I am not able to use the method `click()`.

Do you have any experience regarding that?
Do I need to find the button in another way or use another method to click?

Thank you in advance.

So far i tried to execute the following code:
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tm-visible > .tm-element .tm-columns .tm-button")).click();`

Comment: Can you share the error/Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, the click action may not work properly due to various reasons, such as the element being obscured by another element, or JavaScript event listeners not being triggered.
In such cases, you can try using JavaScriptExecutor to perform the click action. In such cases, you can try using JavaScriptExecutor to perform the click action. Here's an example of how to do that with your current code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

// Assuming 'driver' is your initialized WebDriver instance
WebElement buttonElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tm-visible > .tm-element .tm-columns .tm-button"));

// Use JavaScriptExecutor to perform the click action
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", buttonElement);
```

Comment: thank you so much! It works while using this. Great and quick answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `HTML` you provided, I can see the button you want to click has a class attribute of `tm-button`. So you can try below ways:

***Using Xpath***

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'tm-button')]")));
button.click();
```

***CSS Selector***

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".tm-button")));
button.click();
```

***Using className***

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("tm-button")));
button.click();
```

***Import***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Hope this will solve your issue.